# Laravel query builder search by status

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

In my project, the user can filter the data according to 3 criteria (declared, in progress, finished).

I pass string, in the url parameters [-1,0,1], in order to obtain the active filters. the statuses are defined according to several data coming from different columns of the database, in other words the information is not stored raw in the database.

How can I retrieve filtered data using Query Builder?

```php
$ret = array_filter(explode(',',', $args), 'is_numeric');
$declared = in_array(1, $ret);
        $progress = in_array(-1, $ret);
        finished = in_array(0, $ret);

 if ($declared == false && $progress == false && $finished == false) {
          // do the treatment for this case....
        }
```

If I have to deal with all the cases like that, I don't think it's very optimized.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: none, the field you use in your query should be declared separately, not mashed with other data in a json field.

Comment: If it is a GET request, you should first know than you can pass an array of data in the request itself:
http://url/?filters[]=1&filters[]=-1&filters[]=0

Then you can do request('filters')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a url like this `/your-link?status=n`, where `n` is an int from -1 to 1.

Now, in your controller you can do something like this:

```
public function yourFunction(Request $request) 
{
  if (in_array($request['status'], [-1, 0, 1])) {
     $data = DB::table('your-table')->where('status', $request['status'])->get();
  }
}
```

I'd recommend you to take a look at pipelines and try to use them with Eloquent or Query builder.

Check out this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XqEJO-wt7s) and see for yourself how you can implement a solution.